# SQL Server Sargable Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I ran a test of a sargable and non-sargable query in Enterprise Manager and was surprised by the Execution Plan.  They both used a Clustered Index Scan.  I was expecting the sargable query to use a Seek.

I used this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestSargable](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestSargable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_TestSargable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([ID] ASC)
GO
```

Sargable Query:

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[Created]
  FROM [dbo].[TestSargable]
 WHERE [Created] > '2014-02-28 23:59:59'
   AND [Created] < '2014-04-01 00:00:00'
```

Non Sargable Query:

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[Created]
  FROM [dbo].[TestSargable]
 WHERE datediff(MM, [Created], '2014-03-01') = 0
```

When I viewed the actual execution plan they both used a Clustered Index Scan.

Am I missing something here or is the first query non-sargable also?

This is running on my dev box using SQLExpress 11.0.2100.

Comment: I don't see any index on `Created`?

Comment: Nope. There isn't one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any suitable index to seek into.

```
CREATE INDEX IX ON [dbo].[TestSargable]([Created])
```

Then you see an index range seek on the sargable version and scan for the other.

[image]

The clustered index key gets added to the non clustered index as a row locator so the index is able to cover both columns in the `SELECT` without any need for lookups.

Comment: That's great and it makes sense. I can see it working but I don't exactly understand how clustered and non clustered indexes work together in a query.  Looks like I have a bit of reading to do.  Thanks!

Comment: @David - I've heard good things about [this site](http://use-the-index-luke.com/)